# Why can I update one field but not another in MongoDB? (MEAN Stack)

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two fields: "password_hash" and "password_token" in my db.user mongoDB collection. I can update "password_hash" from API (curl, through an express route, into a mongoose model) but I can't update "password_token" using nearly the exact same code. I can modify either 'manually' from Studio3t, but that would defeat the purpose of writing an API. I also think that means this behavior is not related to indexes, validators, etc. on the database collection, since I'm allowed to save values in either field. When I try to do the same from the API, I get no error message, only  `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }` and no updated field.

Here is the abbreviated document:

```
"username" : "user1", 
"password_hash" : "$2a$10$pVTT8FS.WV.sba1wvVwYMu7hMqaGkP1toJx5PGMXrl/ZnLyLtqsYy", 
"password_token" : ""
```

Here are the curl commands I'm using:

```
# curl -w '\n' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "username": "user1"}' http://localhost:3000/users/save_hash
{"success":true,"message":"Saved a hash for user1."}

# curl -w '\n' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "username": "user1"}' http://localhost:3000/users/reset_user
{"success":true,"message":"Saved a reset token for user1."}
```

...both return success, as written, but the second has no effect on the DB field "password_token".

Here are the structurally identical express routes:

```
router.post('/save_hash', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) logger.error(err);
        if (user) {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                if (hash) {
                    User.saveHash(user.username, hash, err);
                    return res.json({success: true, message: 'Saved a hash for ' + user.username + '.'});
                }
            })
        }
    })
});

router.post('/reset_user', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) logger.error(err);
        if (user) {
            crypto.randomBytes(20, (err, buffer) => {
                if (buffer) {
                    const token = buffer.toString('hex');
                    User.resetToken(user.username, 'test', err);
                    if (err) {logger.error(err) } else {
                        return res.json({success: true, message: 'Saved a reset token for ' + user.username + '.'});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

And here are the structurally identical methods on the models:

```
module.exports.saveHash = function (username, password_hash, callback) {
    const query = {'username': username};
    User.update(query, { $set: { 'password_hash': password_hash }}, (err_update, raw) => {
        if (err_update) { logger.error(err_update); } else {console.log('raw data: ', raw)}
    })
};

module.exports.resetToken = function (username, token, callback) {
    const query = {'username': username};
    User.update(query, { $set: { 'password_token': token}}, (err_update, raw) => {
        if (err_update) { logger.error(err_update); } else {console.log('raw data: ', raw)}
    })
};
```

The curl, route, and model for "password_hash" work as expected. The same duplicated to update "password_token" do not work. Even the following modifications work:

```
module.exports.resetToken ...
User.update(query, { $set: { 'password_hash': token}}... // works. updates "password_hash" to the token value.

module.exports.resetToken ...
User.update(query, { $set: { 'password_hash': 'test'}}... // works. updates "password_hash" to 'test'.
```

...but if I modify saveHash(), which currently works to update "password_hash", so that it should instead "password_token", it does not modify "password_token":

```
module.exports.saveHash ...
User.update(query, { $set: { 'password_token': 'test'}}... /* Does not work. returns  { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } ...and does not modify "password_token". */
```

...So it appears there is 'something wrong' with the password_token field itself, since I can update a different field with the exact same code.

For what it's worth: all the documentation I've read says I should be able to call update() on a field that does not yet exist and it will be created by an implicit $set, but I have not found that to be the case. I have had to create both "password_hash" and "password_token" using MongoShell before they can be updated:

```
db.users.update({},
  {$set : {"password_token":""}},
  {upsert:false,
  multi:true})
```

...so I wonder if I might be in version hell and I'm finally seeing a symptom.

TL:DR; I can update one field "password_hash" just fine, but another field, "password_token" (and any additional fields I add) cannot be updated and return no error, using basically the same curl, route, and model method. What gives?

Comment: Are the additional fields like `password_token` defined in your `User` schema?

Comment: Yes, the new fields are missing from the User schema. Every time I add a new field....Every single time.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, given by JohnnyHK, is that the new fields I'm creating in the DB were not also defined in my User schema.

I have actually made this same mistake before. The lack of error and the only tip off being that the update operation failed means I need to tie a string around my finger any time I add a new field to a document.